# Retrieving dates from Google Custom Search

Tags: java, api, google-custom-search

I am currently developing a Java application based on Google Custom Search API, using their [Java libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/customsearch/v1).

According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#web), they associate a date to each indexed Web page:

> **Page Dates:** Google estimates the date for a page based the URL, title, byline date and other features. This date can be used with the `sort` operator using the special structured data type date, as in `&sort=date`.

I want to retrieve the date associated to all the results returned for a given request. However, I didn't find anything related to this task in Google's documentation: there are parameters one can use to sort the results by date, or focus on a certain period of time, but nothing regarding retrieving the precise dates themselves. And I couldn't find any reference to this problem on the Web neither.

So, I am turning to SO to ask these questions:

1. Is it even possible to do that through Google's API? How?
2. Otherwise, is there a workaround?